# Using computer as media player while playing games

Tags: windows-8, video, vlc-media-player, desktop-computer

Is it possible to: On 1 screen (tv hdmi exit) watch full hd movie with sound.
while on my normal monitor (with usb headset) play a game or watch a difrent movie? (with difrent program)

I know I can extend my screen and I know I can do 2 things at once.
The problem comes with the sound part of it all.

Windows has no way of appointing a program to a specific sound exit and I don't know if a program like vlc hase a built in option.

What I want is:

While my famaly is watching tv (vlc)(movie of my pc), I want to normaly use my pc (firefox youtube/itunes) at the same time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 basically supports directing the sound output to any audio device installed in your system with the new Core Audio APIs. This works with Windows Media Player, VLC uses it's own settings, but you can also select a specific sound device in the VLC preferences.

For selecting a specifc output in Windows Media Player, look [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/b1d1acac-1f21-4d23-8d68-98964d67c2c7/) for example.

With games, this can be more complicated, especially with some old one, but it may work nonetheless.